# Finding parameters to a $Z^2$ normal distribution

Tags: probability

The question asked that given $Z$ which has a normal standard distribution find $X=Z^2$.
Using the method of transformation I found $X = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^\frac{-x}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$.

The second part of the question whether X has a gamma distribution and what are the value of alpha and beta?
This is the part I'm stuck on.

I know that the gamma distribution is
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(k) \theta^{k}} x^{k-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got $c x^{-1/2} e^{-x/2}$ and the density for the Gamma distribution is a constant times $x^{k-1} e^{-x/\theta}$.  Notice that $e^{-x/\theta}$ is the same as $e^{-x/2}$ precisely if $\theta=2$.  And $x^{-1/2}$ is the same as $x^{k-1}$ precisely if $k-1=-1/2$.

Comment: That what I originally thought but the question is asking for beta and alpha.

Comment: What I wrote gives you the parameters that identify the particular Gamma distribution.  If the book is parametrizing the family of Gamma distributions by calling the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you need to look at which of those corresponds to what you're calling $k$ and which to what you're calling $\theta$.  It is somewhat conventional to use the letter $\alpha$ for what you're calling $k$ and $\beta$ either for what you're calling $\theta$ or for what you're calling $1/\theta$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Another parametrisation of the Gamma distribution density is $$\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha \,-\, 1} e^{- \beta x }$$

so you need to match $-\frac{1}{2}$ with  $\alpha - 1$ and match $-\frac{x}{2}$ with $- \beta x$.